# NFS cluster: how do I find out what is causing a file deletion?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a NFS server and a group of systems that involves about 50 machines using it for home directories. I have an intermittent bug where all the files at the top level of my home directory get deleted. How on earth can I track down what's causing this?

root_squash is on. Therefore I suspect a rogue cron job running under my user ID. Is there an easy way to track what file accesses and deletions come from what system, without heavily loading the server being monitored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like `inotify` on the 'homes' folder: when it reports file deletion activity, write down this date and look into `nfswatch` logs which will tell you who, when, where, and what for :)

I haven't tried it, but believe that's the right path.

Comment: Sounds promising, will try it.

Comment: Note that you need to run anything that uses inotify on the server - running it on a client will only capture I/O from that client